# Laravel upload array

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create an array that I will add to the values. Then in another function, I would like to update the model based on the values from this array.

```php
<?php

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public $uploadedPhotos = array();

    public function doSomething()
    {
        // My code...
        array_push($this->uploadedPhotos, 'value');
    }

    public function update()
    {
        foreach ($this->uploadedPhotos as &$value) {
            Image::where('value', $value)->update(array(
                'value' => 'other_value'
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need call public class `doSomething` on update to get result `array push`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this 2 way :

1) upload photos using for loop and push values in array , then pass that array as parameter to your second function that will update other table

2) second way is to upload image , update other table  - one by one in for loop

Comment: My problem is that one function saves the image and another saves the other model to the base - the announcement. I would like to update all saved images with the id value of this ad after saving this ad.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 different route urls which point to separate controller functions `doSomething` and `update`, then you can not directly assign  the data as class's public property. Because each time a new controller instance will be created when a route is called.

You can either store those values in session or more simply pass the data back to blade view of second action if both urls are redirected back to back.